# Getting taxonomies specific to categories

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, taxonomy, sidebar

I have categories set up for car manufacturers.

I have 4 custom taxonomies that are also set up: color, starburst, offer_type, and logo_count.

Each post I upload to my wordpress has values for all 4 of those taxonomies and is assigned a category. I have a custom page template setup to display all posts that have the same category as the current page's slug.

query_posts:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future&posts_per_page=-1');?>
```

My end goal is to display the taxonomies in the sidebar and allow users to visit a manufacturer's page, and filter the content they want to see based on their selections in the sidebar.

I know how to display the taxonomies in the sidebar, I'm just not sure how I would have the content filtered.

Comment: If you're going to -1 at least say why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question. Still not sure how to implement it myself, but a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) does this perfectly.